# android - GMaps V2 - Get the Tile Size in Pixels

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I'm using Google Maps V2 for Android and am trying to create a method to get the size of a tile in pixels to calculate the pixel zoom level.  Here is the code I have:

```
private int calculateZoomLevel() { 
   int ht, screenWidth; 
   DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
   getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
   ht = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
   screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

   double equatorLength = 40075004; 
   double widthInPixels = screenWidth;
   double metersPerPixel = equatorLength / 256; 
   int zoomLevel = 1; 
   while ((metersPerPixel * widthInPixels) > 1000) { 
       metersPerPixel /= 2; 
       ++zoomLevel;
   }
   Log.i(TAG, "zoom level is: "+ zoomLevel);
   return zoomLevel;
}

public float metersToEquatorPixels(final float meters) { 
   return meters / EQUATORCIRCUMFENCE * getWorldSizePx(); 
}

int getWorldSizePx() { 
   return 1 << getPixelZoomLevel();
}

int getPixelZoomLevel() { 
   return calculateZoomLevel() + getMapTileZoom(mTileSizePixels);
}

public static int getMapTileZoom(final int tileSizePixels) { 
   if (tileSizePixels <= 0) {
       return 0;
   }

   int pixels = tileSizePixels;
   int a = 0;
   while (pixels != 0) { 
       pixels >>= 1;
       a++;
   }
   return a - 1;
}
```

I see in the GMaps V2 documentation you can use the Tile class to get the width and the height of the Tile but I'm not sure how to get the tile data for the data[] parameter.  Am I on the right track here?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.